# Opening a text file and using findall in a loop - IndexError

Tags: python

**I apologise in advance as I can't send the .txt, however, it doesn't matter the content, the error is always the same.**

I'm trying to use Python's find all feature to find when a specific term occurs *even though this is pretty pointless)*

The following is the code:

```
doc = open("Folder1/10-06-2017.txt",'r')
for x in range(1,9):
   findall("Good[\s\S]*?Afternoon", doc.read())[x]
```

Is there something wrong with the syntax? Because I continuously get `IndexError: list index out of range`.

Comment: Um, what is `document`, is that suppose to be `doc`? If it is, then on the second iteration, `doc.read()` **will always be an empty string**. Why is this in a loop anyway?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The reason for it being in a loop is...complicated...but I apologise, yes it was doc = document (fixed it). Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: `print(findall("Good[\s\S]*?Afternoon"))` what do you see?

Comment: yes. save the result of using `.read` to another variable, and use *that string* in a loop.

Comment: Your code assumes that `findall` will return an array that has length `x` where 1 <=x <= 9.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `document.read()`, you `read` the `data` from the `file`, but this can only be done once (after, you will just get an empty `string`).

You are calling this line multiple times in the `for-loop`:

```
findall("Good[\s\S]*?Afternoon", doc.read())[x]
```

The first `iteration` of the `for-loop` will work fine, however after that, `document.read()` will return an empty `string` so then `re.findall` will return an empty `list` and then when you try to get the value in an empty `list` at position `x`, you get an `IndexError`, as there is nothing there as the `list` is empty!

What you want to do, is save the `list` returned by the `findall` part to  a `variable` and then in your `for-loop`, access that `variable`. This way, you only `read` from the `file` once and won't experience any errors.

The code for this would look something like:

```
doc = open("Folder1/10-06-2017.txt",'r')
matches = findall("Good[\s\S]*?Afternoon", doc.read())

for x in range(1,9):
   matches[x]
```

I'm not exactly sure what you want to do with the `x` term from the `list` (because at the moment, you aren't doing anything with it), but at least it will work as you want now...

Finally, it is always best practice to close your `file` after you are finished with `reading` from it. You can do this `2` ways. The first being to add the line:

```
 doc.close()
```

to your code at some point (probably after defining `matches`).

The second (probably better as if an error is thrown, the file will still be closed) way would be to put that portion of the code inside a `with`:

```
 with open("Folder1/10-06-2017.txt", "r") as doc:
    matches = findall("Good[\s\S]*?Afternoon", doc.read())

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I know my question was crappy, but you instantly solved my issue.